# What is the difference between these two expressions for the partition function, Z?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function, density-of-states

What is the difference between these two expressions given for the partition function, Z?

$$Z = \sum_{i}e^{-\varepsilon_i/kT}$$

$$Z = \sum_{j} g_je^{-\varepsilon_j/kT}$$

where each energy level has $g_j$ terms of the same energy $\varepsilon_j$, i.e $\varepsilon_i = g_j\varepsilon_j$.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same expression, just with different accounting of states.  (Your energy relation at the end is incorrect.)  However, it is sometimes useful to carry the $g_j$ coefficients around, because certain quantities are most easily found by differentiating with respect to the $g_j$.  This can even be done when there is no degeneracy; you just set $g_j=1$ at the end.

Comment: I think that energy relation that was provided to me confused the matter. How are the states accounted for though, in the first expression?

Comment: In the first one, you have a sum over the possible states of the system.  In the second, the sum is over the possible energies, so you multiply by the degeneracy of each energy level to get an equivalent expressions.